# Hibernate placeholder ignored

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm developing a simple standalone Java application using Spring and Hibernate to try to learn them.

I'm having some problems in the configuration of Spring and Hibernate, in order to really create some "useful" result from the code...

I've tried to follow the examples as reported in the book "Beginning Hibernate 2nd edition" and "Pro Spring 3", but i'm having , regarding Hibernate, this problem (i'm using log4j for the logging) :

```
1824 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@38638273: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,personaDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${jdbc.driverClassName}]
```

It seems that the placeholder is ignored in the parsing of the configuration files

Here i've have copied an extract of them :

**app-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" >
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>




<bean id="personaDao" class="org.bladela.dataaccess.persona.PersonaDaoImpl">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

        <session-factory>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>

            <mapping class="org.bladela.dataaccess.persona.Persona"/>



        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**jdbc.properties :**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employeemanagementdb
jdbc.username=bladela
jdbc.password=password
```

if i substitute all the placeholders with their values, the program goes on and it connects to the db (if i substitute only one...the error "goes" to the next one)

then it return an incorrect result (an empty list when it should return a list with one element) but maybe i'll ask about it later, if i can't solve it.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` declared in your context. How are property placeholders supposed to be resolved?

One solution is to add

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```

to your context.

Comment: thanks...it worked (sorry to have bothered you)

now i have to understand why the query list returned is empty...work for tomorrow...

again thanks

Comment: @bladela You're welcome. That's what we are here for. Consider upvoting and accepting answers (and questions) that were helpful.

Comment: i've tried...but i have not the required reputation to upvote you

i'll accept your answer as soon as the site will permit me :)